# Struggling with getting Maya-Models into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

I recently purchased a few assets online, which are all Maya ASCII-Files, sometimes with some Textures as PSD files, sometimes not.
I want to know how to get these Models into Unity and make them look like they were intended to look like. When i open up a model in maya, for example a tree, it just looks like this:
[image: Tree]

When i drag this file into Unity and put it into some scene, it looks about the same. What do i need to do?
I am a programmer and i have absolutely no experiences with Maya.
I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: FYI you can really google a lot of info "Maya import Unity3D"

Comment: I looked up some pages and tutorials, but they always start off with a model where the textures are applied to the model.

Comment: I am a maya user and can help. There are just many problems that could cause the white stuff you see now. It's  likely that no material is assigned. If you provide link to the tree model in the scene, I will see what's wrong with it and tell you how to fix it and the rest of your assets. Just make sure to provide all files that came with the tree in your question if you want help.

Comment: @Programmer do you still want to help me or nah?

Comment: I did not see your notification because you did not use @ in your second to last post. Always use that. The only reason I saw this is because you used @ sign to notify me in your last comment. I will take a look at it later on today.

Comment: @Programmer okay, thank you :)

Comment: @OfficerBacon I just looked at it. I has the usual 2 Materials. **LeafBunch_Mat** for leafs and **TreeBark_Mat** for the tree bark. They are all missing the textures. **LeafBunch_Mat** is missing the **Color Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumLeafBunch_01_Diff.tif` texture, **Transparency Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumLeafBunch_01_Diff.tif`, **Bump Map** map `HEO_AmericanSweetgumLeafBunch_01_ddn.tif`, and **Specular Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumLeafBunch_01_Spec.tif`

Comment: **TreeBark_Mat** is missing **Color Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumBark_01_Diff.tif`, **Bump Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumBark_01_ddn.tif`, and **Specular Map** `HEO_AmericanSweetgumBark_01_Spec.tif`

Comment: Do you have these files?

Comment: I only have the exact same files which are in the archive i uploaded. There's a folder inside the archive which is called texture with two .psd files in it. Are these the missing textures?

Comment: @OfficerBacon Nope. It looks like you have to generate those files I listed above from the two photoshop files. One file is or the leaf and the other one of for the bark. Please look at my answer. I explained how you can fix the rest of the models and provided a fixed version of your file. You need photoshop to extract those files. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Finally you need to learn Maya to be able to do what I said in my answer. You can start from here. https://www.youtube.com/user/MikeHermes65 and for Maya 2016, there is playlist for it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1DKvOM-k3Q&list=PLyMuCmXTUZG5LEtvUhDBtazsoaoFSdOor

Comment: Thank you very much :) i'm going to start with the tutorials as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only were the textures not assigned to the tree, they were not even there. You had to extract each color, bump, normal, spec and transparency maps from the both photoshop files that is sent to you.

The `LeafBunch_Mat` needs Color Map,Transparency Map,Bump Map and Specular Map.
The Transparency map for the `LeafBunch_Mat` is not included in the photoshop file. I looked closer and realized that the Color Map name and Transparency map name are the-same. This means that you can use the Color Map of the `LeafBunch_Mat` as the Transparency Map too.

`TreeBark_Mat` needs Color Map, Bump Map and Specular Map.

In other to fix the rest of the Models, you have to open each photoshop file and open the layer window. There are Diffuse, Specular and Normal Maps in each layer. Enable each one and save each one out.

For the image below,

**1**.The **Diffuse map** should be plugged to **Color** slot in Maya.

**2**.If the Material says Leaf in the name just like the image below, then you also have to plug the **Diffuse map** to the **Transparency** slot in Maya.

**3**.Plug the **Normal map** to the **Bump Mapping** slot in Maya.

**4**.Plug the **Specular Map** in the **Specular Color** slot in Maya.

Once you fix all these, you can then export it to Unity. It should work.

To conclude this, next time you receive a model that doesn't show anything, you have to check which maps are **used** then check which ones are **missing** on the materials then manually re-plug them.

The circled icon in the image below shows that there is a map plugged into this slot. So you must click on it and chose where the maps are located in your computer.

[image]

The circled icon in the image below shows that there is **NO** map plugged into this slot. So, ignore it.

[image]

Here are the maps to change in your **Leaf material**:

[image]

For the **Tree bark** material, you don't need to plug anything to the Transparency slot. Hopefully, this guide you fix other models.

Fixed version. You can download it from [here](http://wikisend.com/download/181092/AmericanSweetgum.mb.zip). Just unzip it Whereever you want and open the `AmericanSweetgum.mb` file.

[image]

Comment: What is the password for this file?

Comment: @OfficerBacon Just did. Good luck with Maya.

Comment: Thank you again, you are a legend ;)

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me a few times that Unity will not found the textures of the imported model. So what I do is once I import the model to Unity a folder with the model and materials will be create. Then I manually import the textures into Unity and finally I go choose the material from the Unity Editor and add the texture to the corresponding material. I don't know if this is your problem, but Is worth to try.